# What is BLCR and why does it fail to update?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, kernel

Evert time the kernel is updated by apt-get upgrade, I can see the following among the output:

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 2.6.35-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 2.6.35-22-generic         
 *       blcr (0.8.2)...                                                 [fail] 
 *       virtualbox-ose (3.2.8)...                                       [ OK ]
```

What can be the problem with blcr and what should I do?

Comment: If the answer bellow satisfies your question can you please mark it complete by clicking in the check mark? That way the question will not show up on the *unanswered questions* list anymore. If you have any further doubts or remarks to this issue add a comment please. Regards

Comment: @bruno-pereira I still have no idea what can be wrong with it, why does it fail.

Comment: Are you still having this issue???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DKMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) is a utility that automatically re-compiles kernel modules (mostly drivers) that aren't part of the Ubuntu kernel distribution every time there is a kernel upgrade.  (Modules need to be compiled against the current kernel.)

BLCR is [Berkeley Lab Checkpoint/Restart](https://ftg.lbl.gov/CheckpointRestart/CheckpointRestart.shtml).  It seems like you installed the `blcr-dkms` package.

Comment: But what may it be needed for and what may cause it to fail?

Comment: It seems like it's an optional dependency of openmpi (it's a dependency of the optional openmpi-checkpoint).  So the only thing I can do is guess that you use an application that uses openmpi?  I think it's mostly used in (scientific) clusters, if that might give you a hint...

Comment: I can guess it was installed with R. But I still have no Idea why does it fail to update.